# Cannot convert uint* to uint[]

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, unsafe

I have this code which doesn't compile:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    private fixed uint myUints[32];
    public uint[] MyUints
    {
        get
        {
            return this.myUints;
        }
        set
        {
            this.myUints = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I know *why* the code won't compile, but I'm apparently at the point where I'm too tired to think, and need some help to put me in the right direction.  I haven't worked with unsafe code in a while, but I'm pretty sure I need to do an `Array.Copy` (or `Buffer.BlockCopy`?) and return a copy of the array, however those don't take the arguments I need.  What am I forgetting about?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to work in a `fixed` context when working with a `fixed` buffer:

```
public unsafe struct MyStruct {
    private fixed uint myUints[32];
    public uint[] MyUints {
        get {
            uint[] array = new uint[32];
            fixed (uint* p = myUints) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
                    array[i] = p[i];
                }
            }
            return array;
        }
        set {
            fixed (uint* p = myUints) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
                    p[i] = value[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah!  I knew it was going to be something embarrassingly simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There may be an easier solution, but this works:

```
public unsafe struct MyStruct
{
    private fixed uint myUints[32];
    public uint[] MyUints
    {
        get
        {
            fixed (uint* ptr = myUints)
            {
                uint[] result = new uint[32];
                for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
                    result[i] = ptr[i];
                return result;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            // TODO: make sure value's length is 32
            fixed (uint* ptr = myUints)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
                    ptr[i] = value[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with `int`, `float`, `byte`, `char` and `double` only, but you can use `Marshal.Copy()` to move data from fixed array to managed array.

Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyStruct s = new MyStruct();

        s.MyUints = new int[] { 
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
            9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
            9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };

        int[] chk = s.MyUints;
        // chk containts the proper values
    }
}

public unsafe struct MyStruct
{
    public const int Count = 32; //array size const
    fixed int myUints[Count];

    public int[] MyUints
    {
        get
        {
            int[] res = new int[Count];
            fixed (int* ptr = myUints)
            {
                Marshal.Copy(new IntPtr(ptr), res, 0, Count);
            }
            return res;
        }
        set
        {
            fixed (int* ptr = myUints)
            {
                Marshal.Copy(value, 0, new IntPtr(ptr), Count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```